# Octave spews invalid characters rather than plotting on top of image

Tags: ubuntu, gnuplot, octave

With Octave 4.2.1, on an Ubuntu 16.04 no-GUI VM, trying to plot on top of an image results in a lot of garbled characters being spewed to a `multiplot>` prompt, complaints of "invalid character" and "not a string variable", and fails to actually plot the requested function.

Since it's running in a headless VM, `graphics_toolkit` is `gnuplot`, the only option. It's conceivable that a different graphics system might fix this error, but I've been unable to figure out how to get `FLTK` or `Qt` working with Octave in this install.

Example:

```
h = figure("visible", "off");
hold on
image(rand(100,100,3))
x = -10:0.1:10;
plot (x, sin (x));
print(h, '-dpng', 'newtry')
```

yields:

```
...
octave:6> print(h, '-dpng', 'newtry')

multiplot> ]A?M@=b?A?VtB>PAAf-BwB6A?&?Ab?.A??qA?'<B?ι@ЇB\?nBG~B@xB??9BF>?A???A??A???A??A??A???AX?B??[B??@?;B}????@B
           ^
           line 0: invalid character 


multiplot> m忚?????????333333?ꚍ?߿????????5??ٿffffff??    ?/K?ӿ
             ^
           line 0: invalid character 


multiplot> ????????????zI7???ffffff????V3??
                    ^
           line 0: invalid character 
...(more like the above)
```

Thanks for any ideas/suggestions!

Comment: Relevant: [***Printing a figure as a png... This should be basic!***](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-octave/2009-11/msg00315.html)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, @SardarUsama - I don't think it's the same issue, because it happens whether I'm trying to save to .png or just render to the screen, but it suggests that I may be missing some library upon which gnuplot depends. No idea what that might be, though.